# Order by a specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL -

```
 ABC (User, Login_time, City)
```

and contains some data in it.

The result I want is Top 5 users form Noida should come at the top in the resultset and rest resultset should be sorted by login_time. See the fiddle here -

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88c203/9

```
create table abc (user varchar(20), login_time date, city varchar(20));

insert into abc values ('A', curdate(), 'Noida'),
                   ('B', '2017-04-16', 'Delhi'),
                   ('C', '2017-04-14', 'Noida'),
                   ('D', '2017-04-18', 'Kanpur'),
                   ('E', '2017-04-13', 'Raebareli'),
                   ('F', '2017-04-16', 'Sitapur'),
                   ('G', '2017-04-17', 'Muradabad'),
                   ('H', '2017-04-18', 'Noida'),
                   ('I', '2017-04-13', 'Lucknow'),
                   ('J', '2017-04-12', 'Noida');
```

The expected result is -

```
'A', 2017-04-19, 'Noida'
'C', '2017-04-14', 'Noida'
'H', '2017-04-18', 'Noida'
'D', '2017-04-18', 'Kanpur'
'G', '2017-04-17', 'Muradabad'
'B', '2017-04-16', 'Delhi'
'F', '2017-04-16', 'Sitapur'
'E', '2017-04-13', 'Raebareli'
'I', '2017-04-13', 'Lucknow'
'J', '2017-04-12', 'Noida'
```

And the query i tried is -

```
select * from (select user, login_time, city from abc
where city = 'Noida'
limit 3
union all 
select user, login_time, city from abc
where user not in (select user, login_time, city from abc
where city = 'Noida'
limit 3)
limit 4, count)
order by login_time
```

When i try to execute the query in fiddle it throws error -

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle doesn't work when I use it.  Put the code in your question.  Also sample data and desired results in the question would help.  It is  unclear what you mean by "top 5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parentheses to combine the separately ordered results.

```
(select user, login_time, city 
 from abc
 where city = 'Noida'
 --order by login_time desc > add this to sort by login_time 
 limit 5
)
union all
(select user, login_time, city 
 from abc
 where city <> 'Noida'
 order by login_time desc
 limit 3
)
```

Because you have to include the non-top 5 rows from Noida in the result-set, you can use a `left join` to get those and order by the login_time.

```
(select user, login_time, city 
 from abc
 where city = 'Noida'
 order by login_time desc
 limit 3
)
union all
(select a1.user, a1.login_time, a1.city 
 from abc a1
 left join (select user, login_time, city 
            from abc
            where city = 'Noida'
            order by login_time desc
            limit 3) a2 --this derived table is the previous result-set of top n users from Noida
 on a1.user=a2.user and a1.city= a2.city
 where a2.user is null       
 order by a1.login_time desc
 limit 7
 )
```

Use a prepared statement to get the number of remaining rows other than the top 3 rows.

```
set @a= (select count(*) - 3 from abc);

prepare stmt from
'(select user, login_time, city 
  from abc
  where city = ''Noida''
  order by login_time desc
  limit 3)
 union all
(select a1.user, a1.login_time, a1.city 
 from abc a1
 left join (select user, login_time, city 
            from abc
            where city = ''Noida''
            order by login_time desc
            limit 3) a2
 on a1.user=a2.user and a1.city= a2.city
 where a2.user is null       
 order by a1.login_time desc
 limit ?
 )';

execute stmt using @a;
```

Comment: There are more than 5 recorde for Noida in the table. So i want that to be sorted in login_time desc. and top 5 should not come again

Comment: i don't understand. the expected result you ask for doesn't seem to be ordered at all.

Comment: I have edited the ques. Here i have taken 3 records as example that 3 users from Noida should come first and rest result should not contain these 3 records and ordered by login_time.

Comment: see the edit..i think this is what you're trying to do.

Comment: Exactly the thing that i want. but is it possible that in second query i can include whole table excuding top 3 records. Means something like LIMIT 4, Rowcount

Comment: just remove `limit` in the second part of the query, which would give you all the remaining rows.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not sorting the rows after removing LIMIT from 2nd query

Comment: i am not sure why. but you can use a prepared statement to get the number of remaining rows after selecting the top 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the users from Noida first, just use:

```
select abc.*
from abc
order by (city = 'Noida') desc,
         login_time desc;
```

Comment: but how would i ensure that only top 3 records would be for Noida and rest would be order by login_time? BTW fiddle is working now.

Answer (score 0):

this will work **if you are sure you'll have 3 record with city='noida'**

```
select * 
from
(
    (
      select user,login_timecity
      from abc
      where city='noida'
      order by login_time
      limit 3
    )
    union
    (
      select user,login_timecity
      from abc
      where x
      order by city='noida' DESC, login_time
      limit 3, x
    )
) t
```

Comment: it is saying undeclared variable 'X'

Comment: @AnkitBajpai this is a template

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select *, 1 as OrderHelp
    from abc
    where city = 'Noida'
    limit 3
union all
select *, 2 as OrderHelp
    from abc
    where user not in (
        select user
            from abc
            where city = 'Noida'
            limit 3
    )
    order by OrderHelp, login_time desc
```